# Compiler error: cannot find symbol, symbol: class JSPWriter, location:class Converter

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I'm new with Java and just trying to compile a class.

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;


public class Converter extends BodyTagSupport{

    private String _to;

    public String getTo() {
        return _to;
    }   

    public void setTo(String to) {
        _to = to;
    }


    public int doAfterBody(){

    try {
        BodyContent bc = getBodyContent();
        JSPWriter out = bc.getEnclosingWriter();
        double result = 0.0;
        if(_to.equals("F")) {
            result = toFahrenheit(Double.parseDouble(bc.getString()));
        } else {
            result = toKelvin(Double.parseDouble(bc.getString()));  
        }
        out.write("Resultado: " + result);

    } catch(Exception E) {

    }   

        return EVAL_PAGE; //tells servlet container to process rest of JSP page.
    }

    private double toFahrenheit(double c){
        return 32.0 + (c*1.8);
    }

    private double toKelvin(double c){
        return 273.0 + c;
    }
```

The compiler error is

> cannot find symbol, symbol: class JSPWriter, location:class Converter

I don't undertand why I get this error, so please help me out.

I've already added the servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar to the CLASSPATH.

Comment: yes, i'm using javac.

Comment: Java is case sensitive.

Comment: as Balusc said.. java is case sensitive. You imported JspWriter but compiler is searching for JSPWriter... did you use JSPWriter as imported class? If so... it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case sensitive. Change

```
JSPWriter out = bc.getEnclosingWriter();
```

to

```
JspWriter out = bc.getEnclosingWriter();
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works.